# could not get data from sqli in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying display those values from database but it shows an error which is written in if condition plz tell me where i am doing wrong????

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Batch b, Vendor v, Product p WHERE 'v.id' = 'b.id', 'p.id' = 'b.id' and 'b.batch_no' = $batchno";

$retval = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

if(!$retval)
{
    die('Could not get data:' . $conn->connect_error);
}

else
{
    echo "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Print Bill'><br>";
    echo "<h3>Bill</h3>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "Vendor Name :{$row['name']} <br> " .
         "Batch No:{$row['batchno']} <br> " .
         "Product Size:{$row['product_size']} <br> " .
         "Product Price Per Unit:{$row['product_price']} <br> " .
         "Product Quantity:{$row['quantity']} <br> " .
         "------------------------------<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: seems mysql connection error, try checking your connection string

Comment: use joins for you sql

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Batch b, Vendor v, Product p WHERE `v.id` = `b.id` and `p.id` = `b.id` and `b.batch_no` = '". $batchno."' " ;

Answer (score 0):

first check your connection if your connected on your database

and try

```
"SELECT * FROM batch b Inner join Vendor v on v.id=b.id inner join Product p on p.id=b.id where b.batch_no=".$batchno
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables and then use 'on' to tell it how to link the tables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Also not sure what $batchno but that maybe opening your query to injections. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

There is and instead of , in your sql query

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Batch b, Vendor v, Product p WHERE 'v.id' = 'b.id' and 'p.id' = 'b.id' and 'b.batch_no' = $batchno";
```